# External Monitor Scaling Issue with elementary OS

Tags: display, hidpi, mixed-dpi

I have a HP x360 Spectre laptop with 2560 x 1440 resolution and a HP 22" External Display with 1920 x 1080 resolution. Everything looks giant on the external display. I'm not really sure how to modify the external monitor to resolve the scaling issue. Is there a way to change scaling without going through painful calculations to make adjustments via xrandr which may or may not work? Is it setting different dpis? Any help is much appreciated.

I'm using the latest elementary OS.

Comment: I have the same issue, Not sure how to fix this. I tried using scaling but did not work properly

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the different DPI of the monitors. I have resolved it in this way with xrandr:

```
xrandr --dpi 276 --fb 1920x1080     --output eDP-1 --off     --output DP-1 --off     --output DP-2 --scale 1x1 --panning 1920x1080 --auto
```

Note that this turns off the laptop display. You can play around with the settings a bit and even use the graphical tool *arandr*.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Elementary isn't using Wayland.
X Window System can't really handle mixed dpi.

I'm really looking forward using Elementary with Wayland.
But in my opinion it's not usable yet.